# Switching Views With Observable Objects in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, navigation, observable, swiftui

I am practicing trying to switch views using observable objects in SwiftUI, but my code isn't working.  I know I can do this with @State, but I would like to get this working with observable objects.  When I click on the image in the content view, the image doesn't change. Can someone help me?

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewRouter: ViewRouter


    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Button(action: {self.viewRouter.currentPage = "Page2"}) {
                Image(viewRouter.currentPage)
            }

            if viewRouter.currentPage == "Page1" {
                Page1(viewRouter: viewRouter)

            }else if viewRouter.currentPage == "Page2" {
                Page2(viewRouter: viewRouter)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(viewRouter: ViewRouter())
    }
  }
```

**ViewRouter.swift**

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {

    let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter, Never>()

   @Published var currentPage: String = "Page1"

  }
```

**Page1.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Page1: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewRouter:ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
         Image("ET-LondonBridge")
        }
    }
}

struct Page1_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Page1(viewRouter: ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

*Page2.swift*

```
import SwiftUI

struct Page2: View {

    @ObservedObject var viewRouter:ViewRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image("BigBen")
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        }
    }
}

struct Page2_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Page2(viewRouter: ViewRouter())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need this line to make all things work. Just comment out this line

```
//let objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<ViewRouter, Never>()
```