# How to switch to another view by each element's onTapGesture of a list in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I tried to add a navigation view in the list as following. But it not works saying `Result of 'NavigationView<Content>' initializer is unused`

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.allItems){ item in
                    TaskRow(item: item)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // TODO: switch to another view                       
                        NavigationView {
                            VStack {
                                Text("Hello World")
                                NavigationLink(destination: AnotherView()) {
                                    Text("Do Something")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And AnotherView is a SwiftUI file as following:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AnotherView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
        }
    }
}

struct AnotherView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnotherView()
    }
}
```

I have tried the solution in stackoverflow [Switching Views With Observable Objects in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58906088/switching-views-with-observable-objects-in-swiftui) and [SwiftUI Change View with Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56797333/swiftui-change-view-with-button). They neither work in my situation.

How to switch to another view by onTapGesture of the list in SwiftUI like following:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(self.allItems){ item in
                    TaskRow(item: item)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        // TODO: switch to another view                       
                        AnotherView()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tap gesture not for view presentation, but for changing a model or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place whole your body into `NavigationView`.

### Example

```swift
struct Item: Identifiable {
  let id = UUID()
  let name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      List {
        ForEach([Item(name: "A"), Item(name: "B")]) { value in
          NavigationLink(destination: X(item: value)) {
            Text(value.name)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct X: View {
  let item: Item

  var body: some View {
    Text(item.name)
  }
}
```